# Systemd Unit for reconnecting wireless on failure

Tags: wifi, systemd

I have a systemd service called conWlan0.service which establishes WiFi connection. Now I want to create another Unit which periodically checks the connection. Is this a reasonable start?

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=conWlan0.service
OnFailure=conWlan0.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/checkWiFi
RestartSec=120
Restart=always
```

The checkWifi script exits 0 if everything is correct and an error code otherwise.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to run periodically, you should use a SystemD timer unit. Having a service unit that keeps restarting is not a good idea because basically you have your system always in degraded mode (one or more services failed to remain up).

More details can be found in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53557536/53538), in the [Arch Linux wiki about SystemD timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) and in the man pages for `systemd.timer`, but the gist of it is like this:

### 1. Setup the check service

`/etc/systemd/system/checkwifi.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=...

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecSTart=/usr/bin/checkWiFi
```

### 2. Setup the timer that starts the check WiFi occasionally

`/etc/systemd/system/checkwifi.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Timer for checkWifi
After=conWlan0.service

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=120

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

### 3. Enable and start the timer unit

```
systemctl enable --now checkwifi.timer
```

Note that when starting the timer, if the `conWlan0.service` hasn't started yet, `systemctl` would block and wait for the timer prerequirements to be fulfilled.